# When does a UIView know how big it is?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, viewdidload, viewdidlayoutsubviews

I have a subclass of UIView that draws a picture onto itself using CAShapeLayers. I want the drawing to adapt to whatever size the UIView is given by AutoLayout. I gave it a `drawGraph()` function that gets its current size from `.bounds.size` and then draws a picture to fit.

I started by calling my drawing function in the container UIViewController's `viewDidLoad()`, but at that point the layout hasn't happened yet so it has whatever bounds it had in the storyboard.

I tried calling it from the view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, but that isn't totally satisfactory either. It gets called twice: first with the bounds from the storyboard, then again with the updated (correct) bounds. There's a pause in between, so the draw and redraw is visible to the user.

How can I tell if a UIView has had its layout constraints applied and is ready to give me accurate dimensions?

Comment: Did you try that in `viewWillAppear` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should draw it in `UIView`'s `drawRect(rect: CGRect)`. Once view needs to draw on screen, this function will be called.

Answer (score 1):

In my subclasses of UIView I usually do the code related to layout by overriding the `layoutSubview()` method. If I remember correctly it's more lightweight than `drawRect(rect: CGRect)`.

But if you're really doing only drawing then you should probably do it in `drawRect(rect: CGRect)`, as that's what Xcode suggests you when you create a new UIView subclass.